# What is the fastest way to create a 2GB file containing random bytes in Java?

Tags: java, random, byte, bit

I want a way to generate a file containing random bits in Java. What will create the random file the fastest?  I want to create files of any specified size containing random bits.  I want to be able to generate a 2GB file in a matter of minutes (less than a minute if possible).  The technique I'm using right now takes hours to do 2GB:

```
...
private static Random r = new Random();

private static int rand(int lo, int hi) {
    int n = hi - lo + 1;
    int i = r.nextInt() % n;
    if (i < 0) {
        i = -i;
    }
    return lo + i;
}
...
fos = new FileOutputStream(hdFiller);
for(long i = 0; i < maxFileSize; i++) {
    int idx = rand(0,32);
    fos.write(idx);
}
fos.close();
...
```

There has got to be a way to do this faster, maybe even in less than a minute for 2GB.

Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you on? If it's unix-ish, you'd be better off doing this at the command line: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.txt bs=4096 count=512` (4096 * 512 = 2meg, adjust as needed for your 2gig).

Comment: How random is random? The more random, the longer it takes. Why does it need to be random at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to generate random bits all at once, rather than looping, take a look at the [java.util.Random method nextBytes(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes%28byte[]%29) which fills the specified byte array with random bytes. Create a byte array exactly large enough for 2GiB of data and you can generate the whole random bit source in one go.

Comment: Don't do this literally as your program will be needing 2GB of memory, and most likely crash due to out of heap memory error. Instead produce the byte array in smaller chunks.

Comment: Somewhat smaller chunks would probably be better, and write it using a `java.nio` FileChannel, possibly as a MemoryMappedFile ([Thinking in Java Memory-mapped files tutorial](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm))

Comment: For a case where each file location is accessed only once the memory-mapped file may not offer much advantage and could cause excessive MMU work. All that is needed for top performance is a direct byte buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping your FileOutputStream with a BufferedOutputStream.